# Is crossing symmetry reliant on using the Feynman propagator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, greens-functions, propagator, s-matrix-theory

If one used the advanced or retarded propagator instead of the Feynman propagator would crossing symmetry necessarily be violated in some scattering amplitudes?